# March 2023 Writing Challenge: Science Fantasy

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

As decided by vote, here's the next challenge, proposed by me:

> You know about science fiction. You know about fantasy. Write a work that straddles both genres.

---

Go onward and write! Then post your story here as an answer, and get feedback in the comments. If you [ask a main site question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) while writing for this challenge, leave a comment below this question or mention it in your answer.

Follow this question if you want to be notified instantly of any new answers.

You can also post and vote on future challenges here: [The next writing challenge could be yours](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2446/34330)

Answer (score 1):

Six inches of water, a pane of glass, and a polyamide weave mere microns thick: that's all that separates me from the vast expanse of space.

"Seareena! You can get closer," Keelie says, working her way over to me with a single measured movement of her tail. She puts her webbed hand on the glass. "It's just a little cold."

"I prefer to experience the sights from a little distance," I reply.

"I came here to tell you something." She puts her other hand on the glass, thumbs touching. "It's something important. Do you see that?" She flicks her head towards her hands, curls bouncing.

I squint. "What?"

"This tiny speck here, that's our destination. In one tide's time it will look so big you can't miss it." Her words come out faster and faster, somersaulting over one another. "In two, we'll be on the surface."

"I don't see it... that gray one? It doesn't look any different from the others. How do you know that's it?"

"Valeen told me. And she's never wrong about these things, you know. That's why it's her at the controls and not either of us, after all."

"If it's her, I'll trust it. We must be ahead of schedule."

Keelie pouts. "Fine, fine I can tell when I'm not wanted. How quickly can you be ready?"

"Before we land. Keelie, you have to get ready too."

The sad expression she's putting on quickly evaporates into a beaming smile. "I'll see you then."

With that she leaves, headed toward the data lab. After she's gone, I swim the opposite direction, towards the launch bay.

I don't take my eyes off the windows until I'm standing in front of the doors. With one hand on each side, I push and the doors part.

Comment: (A half draft.)